# Find and Replace multiple strings using a POSIX extended regular expression

Tags: regex, substitution, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, posix-ere

I am using Snowflake database and hope to find a single expression that will find and replace multiple items.  The column in question has rows containing, Y, Yes, N, NO, and other irrelevant strings.  So, in the example below Y and Yes are replaced with TRUE, N and No are replaced with FALSE and the other strings remain as they are.  I have wasted TOO much time on this.  Any help is MOST appreciated!

```
dog
Yes
No
Y
N
Zip
```

This works:  **REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE,'^y(es)*$','TRUE',1,0,'i'),'^n(o)*$','FALSE',1,0,'i')**
but I hope to reduce it to a single expression because there are other needed replacements and I hope to avoid numerous functions in functions...

This does not work, but I think it shows the goal: **REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE,'(y(es)?)|(N(o)?)','$1TRUE$2FALSE',1,0,'i')**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Comment: Easy: you can't do that with the `regexp_replace`.

Comment: ok, is there another solution?

Comment: You already have it. Use two replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe your data too much, but as [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) says, you can only substitute *one* string per regexp (from many, but to one).

If there is a single word per column, you can always use `DECODE` as a conversion table:

```
DECODE(Lower(VALUE), 'y', 'TRUE', 'yes', 'TRUE', 'n', 'FALSE', 'no', 'FALSE', VALUE)
```